# CSS Line Graph: Multiple lines?

Tags: css, graph

I'm following [this](http://cssglobe.com/post/4175/pure-css-line-graph) tutorial for a project at work, and I was wondering if there is a way to create several lines on the same graph? At the moment I can;t do this without moving the other line along.

Answer (score 0):

The trick is choosing start & end points of lines where options are defined under css file.You will see there that 
**p** stands for position,
**i** stands for **increase**,
**d** stands for decrease and 
**numbers** in those class system represent the value by points.

Adding more **span** elements in **DD** elements will solve your problem.

```
<dd>
        <span class="pi1 i10"><em>36</em></span>
        <span class="pi17 i10"><em>36</em></span>
</dd>
etc...
```

[alt text http://img28.imageshack.us/img28/494/graphz.png](http://img28.imageshack.us/img28/494/graphz.png)

In this case you should separate the image of lines with another color.

Best Regards
Myra

Comment: Is there a way that I can import the line data from a CSV file using PHP?

Comment: I'm sorry Olivia,PHP is not my area of expertise.But what you're saying is possible.

Comment: He spells out a mathematical process behind it, but make no mistake: this sort of thing isn't really intended for prime time, and should maybe just be considered a thought experiment. There are severe limitations to setting up a graph in this fashion.

Comment: What would you say is a good way? I'd rather not use another language like javascript, I would need a PHP or CSS/HTML graph..